# expo camera takePictureAsync ImageManipulator

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

I have a snippet like this

```
takePicture = async function() {
        if (this.camera) {
            this.camera
                .takePictureAsync()
                .then(data => {
                    FileSystem.moveAsync({
                        from: data.uri,
                        to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${
                            this.state.photoId
                        }.jpg`
                    }).then(() => {
                        this.setState({
                            photoId: this.state.photoId + 1
                        });
                        Vibration.vibrate();
                    });
                });
        }
    };
```

Now my problem is I don't know the way how to insert ImageManipulator into this function. My purpose is after takePictureAsync(), the photo will be resized to 108x192 then this photo will be moved to documentDirectory. Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution, here is the code

```
takePicture = async function() {
        if (this.camera) {
            let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
            let resizedPhoto = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(
                photo.uri,
                [{ resize: { width: 108, height: 192 } }],
                { compress: 0, format: "jpg", base64: false }
            );
            FileSystem.moveAsync({
                from: resizedPhoto.uri,
                to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}photos/Photo_${
                    this.state.photoId
                }.jpg`
            });
            this.setState({ photoId: this.state.photoId + 1 });
            Vibration.vibrate();            
        }
    };
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this will cause error, photo.uri could possibly be undefined.

Comment: after taking picture there are a photo object has returned, so uri cannot be undefined